# How to retrieve a distribution of values for a models field using Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model like this:

```
class Question(models.Model):
  #something

class Answer(models.Model):
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question)      
  points_achieved = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

Now I want to query for the distribution of points_achieved: For each question I want to know how many scored 0 points, 1 points, etc.
In python I would do this as follows:

```
dists = []
  for q in Question.objects.all():
    dist = defaultdict(int)
    for answer in q.answer_set.all():
      dist[answer.points_achieved]+=1
    dists.append(dist)
```

How can I accomplish the same using Django's querying methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
from django.db.models import Count
Answer.objects.all().values('question', 'points_achieved').annotate(total=Count('points_achieved')).order_by('total')
```

Source: [Django Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/aggregation/)

Comment: Thank you, just found the (almost) same solution just now :-)

Answer (score 0):

After some more wild-guessing and following [this](http://agiliq.com/blog/2009/08/django-aggregation-tutorial/) tutorial, I managed to come up with this solution:

```
Answer.objects.values('question','points_achieved')
  .annotate(Count('points_achieved'))
```